# Postgres mogrify adding binary to SQL string

Tags: python, postgresql, binary

I am trying to save data using the example in the python project [dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/blob/master/pgsql_example/pgsql_example.py). The error I am getting is towards the end when trying insert data back into the database.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dedupe_orgs.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "dedupe_orgs.py", line 7, in main
    entity.dedupe_orgs()
  File "/orgs.py", line 183, in dedupe_orgs
    c2.execute("INSERT INTO entity_organization %s VALUES %s" % (values, args_str))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "b"
LINE 1: ...d,id,name,created_on,updated_on,entity_id) VALUES b"(0,65,'S...
```

This is the relevant code:

```
num_cols = len(column_names)
    mog = "(" + ("%s," * (num_cols - 1)) + "%s)"
    args_str = ','.join(c2.mogrify(mog, x) for x in full_data)
    values = "(" + ','.join(x for x in column_names) + ")"
    c2.execute("INSERT INTO entity_organization %s VALUES %s" % (values, args_str))
    con2.commit()
    con2.close()
    con.close()
```

I believe the problem is the example was written in Python 2 but I am using Python 3. How can I resolve the error so the 'b' is not added to every query, preventing the data from saving?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but, I strongly recommend sqlalchemy if you are going to interact with a postgres database in your python code. It avoids errors like this because you should almost never be writing raw sql code.

Comment: @melchoir55 I'm actually using sqlalchemy in other areas but was trying to get this example to work before converting it to that. Maybe I should try right now.

Comment: Ok I switched to sqlalchemy and everything is working much better now.

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `args_str` isn't actually of the type string. Are you using a proper debugger like `pycharm`? If so, can you inspect the variable to confirm it is a string before you try to interpolate it?