# Postgres sql script to export specific data from one DB and restore into another DB having same schema

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

The scenarios are as follows: I need assistance with a pgsql dump and restore query

There are two servers A & B with the same database schema, and I would like to export specific data from server A (multiple select statements with some conditions) from certain tables and restore it to server B. A .sql script that allows me to export and restore selected data is what I am looking for.

Example

Server A has a database with two tables, a user and an address. I need to export all users who are over 23 years of age as well as all addresses where the city is Boston. This data needs to be injected into server B with Dserver B, which has a database having the same schema.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup.html

Comment: You can't do that with pg_dump/pg_restore.  1) You can in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) use `\copy`  with a query to export CSV that you can then import into second database again using `psql` and `\copy.. 2) You can use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to directly link the databases and run queries to transfer the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I can't link those two DB and that is the reason I am looking for a different option. Can I do the same using SQL script?

Comment: 1) You don't have access to `psql`? 2) You can use [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) which is what `\copy` is using. Read the `COPY` docs as it runs as the server user, so there are special considerations.

Comment: I am using a python script to export data where I am using postgres copy command  to export data to get the stringified version of the query i am using mogrify method as follows    query = reuseCur.mogrify('SELECT * from table where id in %(id)s', {'id': tuple(ids)}) but the stringified result string is getting with prefix b which is creating issue in copy command

Comment: b"SELECT * from table where id in (1,2,3)"

Comment: I just want stringified query without that character b as follows                   
   "SELECT * from table where id in (1,2,3)"

Comment: Same issue mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113361/postgres-mogrify-adding-binary-to-sql-string